# Passing data from one form field to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am trying to customize a form on a Wordpress site. This form has two fields which will share the same exact data (Post Title and Location). Rather than have the user enter the same information in two different fields, I am looking for a way to have the user enter the Location in the Location field, and then have that same input passed on to the Post Title field (which will be hidden) before the form is submitted.

I have done some research on this and it seems like jquery is need to make this happen. I'm not at all knowledgeable with jquery, so I need some clarification on how to make this happen. If you could, please explain how to implement the jquery code into the page. Do I have to create a jquery file and then call that file on this page? As I said, I know nothing about jquery. Thanks.

Note: Having issues with jquery event that will work with autocomplete drop down. All events I've tried are only passing text I type manually. When I click on an autocomplete dropdown suggestion, any text I didnt type manually is not passed to the second field.

Here is the current code I am working with:

```
<input type="text" id="location" name="location" tabindex="17" data-geo="formatted_address" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Provide full street address', APP_TD ); ?>" class="required" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $project->_hrb_location ); ?>" />
    <input name="post_title" type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $project->_hrb_location ); ?>" class="required" />
```

Comment: So all you want is to have the field `Post Title` to have the same value which is entered in `Location` first?

Comment: Yes, without having to type the same thing twice.

Comment: It seems like its the jquery event thats the issue at this point, ive tried many including onclick, onsubmit, onblur...Any ideas on what even will work with an autocomplete drop down. Right now Im only getting what I manually type in to pass on to the second form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaScript function is going to take the value entered in the field `Location` and will post to the field `Post_ID` accordingly.
JS:

```
<script>       
 var swap_val = function  (val){
            var input = document.getElementById("post_title");
            input.value = val;
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
Enter Location to see it in the Post ID:
<input type="text" id="location" name="location" tabindex="17" data-geo="formatted_address"  
class="required" value="" onkeyup='swap_val(this.value);'/>
Post ID:
<input name="post_title"  id = "post_title" type="text" value="" class="required" />
```

[A Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvOwNJ)

Comment: This solution is very close to working. The only issue I am having now is that only what I manually type is being carried over to the title field. The location field is an auto complete field. So if I start typing an address, and then click on an auto complete suggestion, only what i manually typed is passed along to the title.

Comment: @JohnThornton _Yes, without having to type the same thing twice._ Isn't this doing the same thing?

Comment: For example, if I type in location 123...and then select 123 Main Street from an auto complete drop down, then only 123 is passed to the title field...becuase that is all i manually typed. Anything that is populated by auto complete is not passed to the title field. In the answer below from Alvin mentions the 'blur' event handler. Would you be able to incorporate that into the suggestion you gave me? Or is there another way to make your code pass the entire address along (including autocomplete)?

Comment: I tried changing onkeyup to onblur and also onchange but neither worked. i still only get the characters I actually type to pass through.

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, I was able to get this solution to work by swapping onkeyup for onfocusout.

Comment: @JohnThornton Ahh, I'm glad you got through this :-)

Comment: The codepen is no longer showing the attached code FYI. It works if you input the code you have above though, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#location').on("keyup", function(){
     $("input[name=post_title]").val($('#location').val());
   });
});
</script>
```

On every `keyup` that will add the value of the input with the id of `location` and 'place' it inside the hidden input with the name `post_title`

Comment: I added this to my header.php file. When I submit the form I am getting an error that says "No post title".

Comment: Is there anything I need to do other than add that script to my header? Can I use my php code above as is, or is there a change I need to make to that as well?

Comment: Is your hidden form being loaded via an ajax?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a JavaScript library which has a few simple basics and a lot of advanced topics. Here are a couple relevant points to your question:

1. You select elements through the DOM just like CSS selectors. Here you select every element with an ID of 'location'

   *var input = $("#location");*
2. You can bind events to elements, such as on click, blur, mouse over, load, etc.
3. You would include jQuery as a script in the head tag of your HTML, and any scripts you have that require jQuery can be in their own js files or in the HTML/PHP document you're working with.

See my fiddle as an example of how to bind the blur event (focus on an element is removed... IE tab off the text input).

http://jsfiddle.net/2maw8xo4/1/

```js
var input = $("#location");
var showme = $("#showme");

$(input).on("blur", function() {
  showme.val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="location" name="location" tabindex="17" data-geo="formatted_address" placeholder="Provide full street address" class="required" value="" />
<input type="text" id="showme" disabled />
```

Comment: Where do i put this on the form page? 'var input = $("#location");
var showme = $("#showme");

$(input).on("blur", function() {
  showme.val($(this).val());
});'

Comment: you could put it in a script tag at the end of the body and it will run, but I would wrap the JavaScript in the document ready tag: $( document ).ready(function() { //code goes here 
});

Comment: This works but the googleapis script breaks other jquery I have on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in WordPress:

First form - looking for the name="YourNameValueHere" variable and calling a "GET" request instead of a "POST".

`<form class="mailform" method="get" name="grab" action="Your-URL-here-or-file.php">
      <fieldset>
        <label >
          <input type="text"  name="first_name" />
        </label>
        <label >
          <input type="text" name="last_name" />
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="text" name="email_address" />
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="text" name="phone"/>
        </label>
        <div class="controls-submit">
          <button class="btn-large" type="submit">Get started now!</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>`

Form #2 spits out the info in the input fields

These are the vars that grab the name input fields in the first form with "GET" request.

`<?php
        $firstName = $_GET['first_name'];
        $lastName = $_GET["last_name"];
        $emailAddress = $_GET["email_address"];
        $phoneNumber = $_GET["phone"];

    ?>

    <form method="POST">
    <p>First Name*</p>
        <input required type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>">
    <p>Last Name*</p>
        <input required type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>">
    <p>email*</p>
        <input required type="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo $emailAddress; ?>">
    <p>Phone*</p>
        <input required type="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phoneNumber; ?> ">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of different event handlers to achieve this quite easily:

http://jsfiddle.net/f84shzxu/

The event handler can be asked to execute on different events, two of these include:

**1)** `blur` - After the current element has lost focus.

**2)** `keyup` - After button presses

The example includes both methods.

The basic structure of the event handlers are:

```
// On 'blur' will update when you click off the field
$('#location').on('blur', function(){
    $('#location2').val($('#location').val());
});

// On 'keyup' will update after each key press
$('#title').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#title2').val($('#title').val());
});
```

If you are using autocomplete, try using the `blur` event handler.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Where do I add this code? Do I need to make any changes to the code I included in my question above?

Comment: @JohnThornton - You can create a new javascript file which includes my code from the example (you may need to change IDs to match yours) and import it as you would any other javascript file (it would be best to only import it on necessary pages). Regarding your original code, it should be mostly fine but I would add an ID to the second input so it can be uniquely targetted. Does that help?

Comment: I have not been able to get it to work. It seems to work well in fiddle. But when I incorporate it into the site its not working. I changed the variables tp match mine. I have even tried including the script in the header and in the body of the form page. Any idea?

Comment: @JohnThornton - Do you get any console.log errors? You can test the way you're adding scripts by the page by trying to add a test script in `header.php`... maybe something like `alert('Hello!');`... this way you can start eliminating options. Let me know how it goes.